# Projective transformation for ideal points

Tags: transformation, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

I know that for a projective transformation $T:PR^2 \mapsto PR^2$ it will have the form of
$$T(X)=AX$$
where A is a matrix and X is a vector in homogeneous coordinates.

I also know that this $T$ maps ideal points to itself. $ie,$
$$T(X)=X$$

So $X$ represented in homogeneous coordinates will be $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

then if I were to represent the mapping of $X$, it will look like the following
$$T(X)=
AX=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_3\\
a_3&b_3&c_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
*
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How would I prove that this transformation is in fact a translation or radial transformation.

I have tried multiplying the matrix and the vector and I got something like this:
$$a_1x+b_1y+0=x\\
a_2x+b_2y+0=y\\
a_3x+b_3y+0=0\\
$$
from here I have trouble showing that it is a translation or radial transformation

Comment: What do you know about eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: Note: $T(X)=X$ means $AX=\lambda X$ for any nonzero $\lambda$.

Comment: @amd I know that when $Ax=x$, it means that x is the Eigenvector and 1 is the Eigenvaule is 1. But how does that prove its a translation though?

Comment: Assuming that you really do have $Ax=x$ for ideal points, you now know what the transformation does on a certain subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Now examine what it could do on a complement of this space. Another take on this is that, relative to the standard basis, two columns of $A$ are now determined.

Comment: However, per @Berci’s comment, are you sure that, viewed as an automorphism of $\mathbb R^3$, $T$ is the identity map on ideal points? The condition that $T$ maps ideal points to themselves only requires that if $X$ is the homogeneous vector that represents an ideal point, then $AX=\lambda X$ for some scalar $\lambda$ that might depend on $X$; $AX=X$ is a much stronger condition than this. It doesn’t change the proof tremendously, but you do have to take a bit more care with it.

Comment: A more fruitful approach might be to examine what $T$ does to lines on the projective plane.

Comment: @amd so I have tried it and figure that lines just maps to another line on the projective plane under the transformation $$T(l)=(A^-1)*l$$
But how can I use this fact to prove its a translation or radial transformation

Comment: Every nonsingular projective transformation maps lines to lines. What can you say about the relationship between a line and its image under this particular transformation? Hint: what is a geometric interpretation of an ideal point?